# 403 forbidden using fastcgi

Tags: apache, fastcgi, http-status-code-403

Trying to set up a [ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/) server, using apache 2.2 with fastcgi on Windows 7 (no, Linux isn't an option).  I'm using (basically) the default httpd.conf, with mod_fcgid and mod_rewrite loaded, and 
`Include C:\mars\reviews\conf\apache-fastcgi.conf` added at the bottom.  This too is the default, excepting the `Order`, `Allow`, and `+Indexes`.  The trouble is, when I attempt to load the site, I get 403 for `/` (which, according to the rewrite rule, would become `reviewboard.fcgi`).  I added `+Indexes` to prove that yes, in fact, I can access those directories, so it doesn`t appear to be a permissions problem.

When I add `ExecCgi`, those 403 errors turn into 404 errors!  I'm at my wits end, and over my head.

The contents of `C:\mars\reviews\conf\apache-fastcgi.conf` (with `ServerName` redacted):

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

    FastCGIServer "c:/mars/reviews/htdocs/reviewboard.fcgi" -socket "c:/mars/reviews/tmp/fastcgi.sock"
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName #redacted
    DocumentRoot "c:/mars/reviews/htdocs"

    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    Alias /media "c:/mars/reviews/htdocs/media"
    Alias /errordocs "c:/mars/reviews/htdocs/errordocs"

    # Error handlers
    ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

    <Directory "c:/mars/reviews/htdocs">
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Direct all other requests to the fastcgi server
    RewriteEngine on
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
        RewriteRule ^/(errordocs.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
        RewriteRule ^/(errordocs.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
    </IfModule>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /reviewboard.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

What on Earth is going wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Christian Hammond at ReviewBoard, he pointed me to [this django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8742).  It turns out that django doesn't support FastCGI on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you have mod_fcgid installed, but FastCGIServer-statement is in mod_fastcgi-section. I'd started here.